# How to override static methods inside a Junit test?

Tags: java, junit

I have a `static` method add in a class `SourceClass`  and I want to override the functionality of add method in JUnit test.
example:

```
public class SourceClass {
   protected static int add(int a, int b){
      //Do something
   }
}
```

this SourceClass dont have any constructors.
Junit CLASS:

```
public class TestClass
{
 public void addTest()
  {
    //Trying to Override the add method here.
  }
}
```

when i am using `@Override`, it is not working.
can someone suggest me, how can we achieve this?

Note: i should not use `@PrepareForTest` in test class.

Comment: which version of java are you using?

Comment: You can not override a method, if you not extend a class. As i understand your belongings, you men you would like to mock this method

Comment: Overriding doesn't make sense in this context.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to? static methods are supposed to be used directly. Also, for static methods you don't need to create object. As add method is protected, I assume you're following the same package structure for test as you're for source,

```
public class TestClass
{
 @Test
 public void addTest()
  {
    assertEquals(SourceClass.add(2,5),7);
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably because that static method is using a resource like a database.

Comment: @leroneb unlikely, unless everything was declared static. or otherwise connection pool/ resource instance was passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can override a static method, but you won't have RTTI for it. So, you won't get much benefit from the override.

However, as someone said in a comment, you'll only override a method when you extend the class that contains it.